# Amsterdam Day trip

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, amsterdam

I hold an Indian passport and since I have a day layover in Amsterdam I wanted to apply for a transit visa. Is this possible?

Comment: You don't need a transit visa if you are transiting through AMS only (and if you are traveling to the US); but otherwise you'll need a transit visa even if you do not leave the airport.

Answer (score 6):

You can obviously apply for a visa but there is no specific easier-to-get “transit” visa that would allow you to do that.

If you need or want to leave the transit lounge of the airport, you need a regular Schengen visa, with all the same costs and requirements as if you would come for a short touristic stay or any other short-term visit. And you must apply for that visa a few weeks in advance, from your usual place of residence. There are some very limited exceptions but it's generally impossible to get one at the airport or on the road.